# how display text only inside the related input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, ecmascript-6

I have input boxes which are getting enabled when the checkbox of that input box get checked by user. then I want to type in that particular input box, but when I am in a particular input box then my text is showing in the all the input.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
//some imports related to checkbox

export default function componentA() {
  //input
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
 

  //checkbox group
  const [checkedOptions, setCheckedOptions] = useState({});

  const onOSelect = (event) => {
  
    const item = event.target.name;
    const isChecked = event.target.checked;
   

    setCheckedOptions({
      ...checkedOptions,
      [item]: isChecked,
    });
  };

  //data
  const data = [
    { label: "Rock", name: "Rock" },
    { label: "rambo", name: "rambo" },
    { label: "phone", name: "phone" },
    ]

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div >
      <div>
        <Card>
          <Checkbox
            checkedOptions={checkedOptions}
            groupLabel="Checkbox group label"
            onChange={onOSelect}
            options={data}
          />
        </Card>
      </div>
      <Card >
        <div >
          {data.map((item, key) => (
            <div key={key.name} >
              <input
                label={item.name}
                name={item.name}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder="Placeholder"
                isDisabled={!checkedOptions[item.name]}
                value={value}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Looking for a solution, how display my typed text only in the related input field  and get that value in particular state.

Comment: you need to convert value state into map and pass the related fragment into each input.

Comment: You should include email, phone and mail to your state. In your handleChange function, use event.target.name to find which TextBox had been updated, and update your state accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save state per field so something like this will work

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({});
   ....

 const handleChange = (event, fieldName) => {
    setValue(oldState => ({ ...oldState, [fieldName]: event.target.value}));
  };   
   ....
 
 <Input
  isRequired
  label={item.name}
  minLength={4}
  name={item.name}
  onChange={(e, item.name) => handleChange(e, item.name)}
  value={value[item.name]}
  ....
  />
```

don't forget also to point the input to his value in the object by its name, thanks to @andymccullough for pointing it out

Comment: you're missing the important part of what the `value` prop looks like

Comment: @majidbeg I've updated the handleChange function, was missing prentices, copy it and try it now

Comment: @majidbeg added working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-montalcini-7uk5q?file=/src/App.js)